# Filling one field based on another (same attribute table) with Python

Tags: python, pyqgis-3

I have one field with a list of integers. I want to fill another field with the sum of those integers. When I print the results on the Python console, everything is fine. But I don't know how to fill every cell: when I try return, all the features have the same result as the first one. I understand why that happens but I cannot figure out what is the right way. I've spent a while now looking for examples but no one corresponds exactly to what I'm looking for.
In the code below "ESPESSURA" is the field with the list of integers (ex: 40,67), attrs[13] the field I want to fill.

```
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *
from qgis.utils import iface
@qgsfunction(args=0,group='Custom')
def sum_list_str(value1,feature,parent):
    lyr = iface.activeLayer()
    features = lyr.getFeatures()
    idx = lyr.fields().lookupField('ESPESSURA')
    for feat in features:
        attrs = feat.attributes()
        attrs[13]=sum([int(i) for i in attrs[idx].split(',')])
        #return(attrs[13]) -> takes the first result and fills everything with it
        #print(attrs[13]) -> prints the values I'm looking for
        #lyr.updateFeature() -> QgsVectorLayer.updateFeature(): not enough arguments
        #lyr.updateFeatures() -> 'QgsVectorLayer' object has no attribute 'updateFeatures'
    #lyr.commitChanges()
```

(I'm pretty sure there are a lot of inelegant things in the code. Any comment is welcome.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution using expressions:

```
@qgsfunction(args='auto', group='Math')
def get_list_sum(value, feature, parent):
    return sum([int(e) for e in value.split(",")])
```

Then write this expression (e.g., in the field calculator):

```
get_list_sum("ESPESSURA")
```

---

With my own data and fields:

[image]